# jQuery .fadeOut method on and element that is being appended after DOM load

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fadeout, effects

*(I am 9 weeks into a boot camp, so I apologize for the potentially rudimentary nature of this...)*

I am appending an element to the DOM (a button) within a conditional:

```
$('.buttonsAndInputs').append(`<button id="clearHistoryButton">Clear All</button>`);
```

When this button is clicked, it runs through a series of functions to empty an array and clear some other content off the DOM. I would like to use the .fadeOut method of jQuery to remove THE BUTTON.

I have this in a subsequent function:

```
$('#clearHistoryButton').remove();
```

I would like to:

```
$('#clearHistoryButton').fadeOut(1000);
```

...so that it disappears in a fancy fashion.

It's not working - it simply waits one second and then - POOF - is gone.

This is my first question. This community has been ESSENTIAL in my growth in this realm and, as always, I appreciate all of you so very much.

Comment: As you are a new contributor, please remember to mark an answer as **accepted answer** if you feel it solved your issue. That way, other contributors would see that your issue has been solved and can concentrate on other questions pending - thank you

Comment: There is no reason I see in your code that would make it not work. https://jsfiddle.net/pe5wrt8q/

Comment: I think the issue was that it's something that is appended after load. I can make hard-coded elements fade-out. 

The accepted answer did the trick, but it did affect functionality (it's simply beyond my understanding at this point to make the button return). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `transition: opacity 1s` in your **CSS** ?

Advantage:
**Hardware accelerated (GPU)**, i.e. it doesn't bother your main processor (CPU) with this task, whereas jQuery's `fadeOut()` function is **software based** and does take CPU resources for that effect.

Steps:

1. **Add** `transition: opacity 1s` to your CSS rules of the desired button element
   here: ( `#clearHistoryButton` )
2. **Add a CSS rule** with `button.fadeMeOut` with `opacity: 0`
3. **Add a simple jQuery function** to add the class ".fadeMeOut" at click
4. **Then remove button** with `setTimeout(function(){$('#clearHistoryButton').remove()},1000)`

Run code snippet

```js
$(function() { // Shorthand for $( document ).ready()

  $("#clearHistoryButton").on( "click", function() {
    // first: fade out the button with CSS
    $(this).addClass("fadeMeOut");

   // then: after fadeOut effect is complete, remove button from your DOM
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#clearHistoryButton').remove();
    },1000);
  });
  
});
```

```css
button {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

button.fadeMeOut {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="clearHistoryButton">Press to hide me</button>
```